# Cannot create a dialog when I receiver push notification

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-dialog

Whenever I receive a push notification, and my app is visible (onStart() / onStop() pairs), I am trying to show a dialog to the user from the GCMIntentService class.
(I have not still switched to the next GCM, actually I did but I had problems, so I switched back to the older one)

```
protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context); //issue here

builder.setMessage("You have a notification").setTitle("Notification");
builder.setPositiveButton("dismiss",
new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
{
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
{
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
}
});

AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
dialog.show();
 }
```

The error I am getting is

> android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application

I know this is a context error and it was written wrong in google's documentation etc...
But what is the way to show a dialog whenever I receive the notification?

Comment: you need to start an activity first. (but your activity can be a dialog)

Comment: @njzk2 if that is the case, I need to know which activity is open at the moment right ? Actually, when the notification comes, a random activity will be open, and I want the dialog to appear there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a dialog, make an activity and set it's theme to `Theme.dialog` or any of its children, and start the activity from the `onMessage` method.

That way your your activity will serve the purpose of a dialog and the problem will go away

Comment: nice idea. lemme try.

Comment: I tried the approach, it works fine, (you need to a the flag of new task to the activity tho.. i learned it the hard way)... however my activity with a dialog theme is taking full space,,, although I Just have a tiny button...(the height of the parent layout is set to wrap content)

Comment: Yeah.. it does take up a lot of space. I was also developing a similar app some time ago.. This was the only solution I found

Comment: the issue is resolved. by setting the height of parent to wrap_content and add the name of the theme hard coding to the activity inside manifest.